# Can we prove Schur's Theorem (existence of upper triangular matrix) with a constructive proof?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I found a few proofs of this theorem that all uses induction, so we are already assuming we have a upper triangular matrix that is $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ and all we need to finish the induction proof is to adjoin the last basis vector. But is there a constructive proof of this theorem? Is there a process like Gram Schmidt that lets us find a basis which gives an upper triangular matrix?

Comment: An inductive proof is constructive, so long as the initialization and induction steps are themself constructive. You can transform the proof into an algorithm by "running the induction backwards". Actually, most algorithms like that, and in particular Gram-Schmidt, are usually proved by induction.

Comment: ohh that makes sense.